# CSS center a div within parent based on actual parent size, not viewpoint size

Tags: css, html

usually margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto would center a div within a parent div, but this solution is based on viewpoint size, meaning if the parent div size is bigger than the viewpoint, this will center the child div only within the viewable portion of the parent div.

How can I center a child div based on the actual parent size, but not viewpoint size of the parent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing another issue. A block element with margin: auto and a set width inside another block element that's wide will center it even if the container is wider than the viewport.

```
.hooge-div{
    width: 2000px;
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px;
}

.small-one{
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #111;
    height: 20px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/EW7Wy/

Answer (score 0):

Using automatic margin-left and margin-right will only take the viewpoint size into consideration if the parent div does not have a specific width.

For example, the parent div below has a specific width and the child is centred based upon that specific width:

```
<div style="width: 1200px; background: blue;">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50px; background: red;">
        I am the child div.
    </div>
</div>
```